# How to change font color/un-flip text inside body using JavaScript method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Note**: This question is about JavaScript method only.

**Q)** Why do I need this JavaScript Code?

**A)** I used **transform: scaleX(-1)** to flip webpage horizontally, I want to use JavaScript to un-flip all texts to Normal.

Here is my question:

> How to use **JavaScript** to change font color inside body using **.redfont** css class and change the text direction (un-flip) to normal?

I highly appreciate any comments and help and please just answer based on JavaScript method only.

```css
    .redfont { color:red; transform: scaleX(-1); }
    .flip { transform: scaleX(-1); }
```

```html
    <html>
 <body class="flip">
 Subject
 <div>Div Text</div>
 <span>Span Text</span>
 <h1>H1 Text</h1>
 <p>P Text</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks in advance

Posted Answer (Not Working)

```js
     $( document ).ready(function() {
     document.body.classList.add("redfont");
     });
```

```css
.redfont { color:red; transform: scaleX(1); }
.flip { transform: scaleX(-1); }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
 <body class="flip">
 Subject
 <div>Div Text</div>
 <span>Span Text</span>
 <h1>H1 Text</h1>
 <p>P Text</p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set inline `scaleX(1)` to override `scaleX(-1)`

```
document.body.classList.add("redfont");
document.body.style.transform="scaleX(1)";
```

Comment: I updated your code on snippet, but as you can see not working. I just want to un-flip texts only using JavaScript. How to do it? Only Texts. not direction of page.